# why this perpetual motion engine does not work and does not break the law of energy conservation?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, power, perpetual-motion

[image]

I came-up with this idea when i was 10 years old , I am not claiming that it is working , I just want to know why it doesnt if it doesnt ?
This engine is supposed to produce infinate energy from magnets .

Comment: Consider any two magnets, in a configuration where they attract each other. The energy you extract by bringing them closer together is exactly canceled out by the energy it costs to separate them again. Now just apply that reasoning to every pair of magnets in your machine.

Comment: To add to @knzhou's comment, note that all poles of all magnets in the system experience an attractive or repulsive force, not just the two closest poles of two closest magnets.

Comment: Yeah i can see , maybe that will prevent it from rotating , btw the image is edited

Comment: If that is true , we should find at every roation degree , groups 2 pairs  of poles that each of the pairs neglect the other pair

Comment: there is no way to get any pair of magnets to "neglect" each other. this is ruled out by the math that describes how magnetic fields propagate through space which no cleverness on the part of the inventor positioning the magnets can overcome .

Comment: there is always an equilibrium point in which the machine will not move